# Islam.SE's 10 year anniversary is coming! Share your ideas for the SE blog announcement here!

Tags: discussion

### June 19, 2012.

That's the day when Islam—StackExchange stopped being an idea on Area51, and was actually launched as a private beta Q&A site.

For those who have done the math, this means that we're fast approaching our **ten year anniversary** as a site. To celebrate, the StackExchange community team would like to include our site in their quarterly blog updates, [as they have done for others in the past](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/).

So this is where you, the Islam—StackExchange community, come in: How do you want this site to be presented? Are there any good questions you would like to highlight? Any great achievements you'd like to point the spotlight on? This is your opportunity to shine!

Answer (score 3):

We can post something like this:

> As the fastest growing religion in the world, there are a lot of
> questions people ask about Islam. Many do not know or have not
> understood the true message of Islam, and others have been
> misinformed. Muslims and non-Muslims alike have gained tremendously
> from this site. We welcome you to visit this site, ask questions, or
> if you are knowledgeable, answer other people's questions. This site
> belongs to all of us. We are waiting for you to visit. May The Lord
> have mercy upon all humans.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't really a Da'wah site, this gives an image that we are actually inviting them to Islam. This is in fact, a StackExchange site regarding Islam, that has little to do with directly portraying good regarding Islam in front of Muslims and Non-Muslims.